# C# Get an object per index on an infinite list of the same object

Tags: c#

I have an object which contain a list of this object.

when the user click on a button I want to add a new object
to one of the object in the list per an index. for example if the index is equal to 2
I want to add an object to the object.object.object(new object()).

how am I trying to get the correct object inside the inifinte object.

any better method then this one?

```
 private void addToCommand(int indexTreeView, ClassForTest.CommadStructure CS)
    {
        if (_indexTreeView == 0)
        {
            _OCommandStructure.Add(CS);
        }
        else if (_indexTreeView==1)
        {
            _OCommandStructure[_OCommandStructure.Count - 1].SubCommandStructure.Add(CS);
        }

        else if (_indexTreeView == 2)
        {
            _OCommandStructure[_OCommandStructure.Count - 1].SubCommandStructure[_OCommandStructure[_OCommandStructure.Count - 1].SubCommandStructure.Count-1].SubCommandStructure.Add(CS);
        }                     
    }


public class CommadStructure : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _Controller;;

 
    private ObservableCollection<CommadStructure> _SubCommandStructure;


    public string NameOfCommand
    {
        get => _NameOfCommand;
        set
        {
            _NameOfCommand = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
  public ObservableCollection<CommadStructure> SubCommandStructure
    {
        get => _SubCommandStructure;
        set
        {
            _SubCommandStructure = value;
          //  NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<object> childNodes = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            foreach (var group in this.SubCommandStructure)
                childNodes.Add(group);
            return childNodes;
        }
    }

    public CommadStructure()
    {      
        NameOfCommand = "";        
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: `var target = _OCommandStructure; for(int i = indexTreeView; i > 0; i--) { target = target[target.count - 1].SubCommandStructure; }; target.Add(CS);`?

Comment: It is highly unlikely you have an infinite list of anything; you would need infinite memory in your computer and, while RAM prices are relatively low, they're not _that_ low. What you appear to be talking about is an unbounded nested structure; there are methods of dealing with those, detailed in questions across SO.

Comment: Thanks this code has done the trick.